# Even if one's preferences are flawless, what might we wish to be done, but think that they oughtn't be done?

Tags: desire

Source: Benatar, David. [*Better Never to Have Been*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199549265) (2008 1 edn). p. 155 Middle.

I don't understand the emboldened sentence beneath. What are some common real-life yens that fit and can instance the titled question? Why would we think that these yens oughtn't be done?

> That the preference for having been born is mistaken lends
>   further support to another (independently) very strong criticism of
>   Professor Hare’s argument. It has been noted that the first premiss
>   of his argument—the logical extension of the Golden Rule—is
>   false. There is a difference between being glad that somebody did
>   something for one and thinking that that person was obligated to
>   have done as he did. **Not everything that we might wish to be done
>   (or are glad was done) is something that we think should be done
>   (or should have been done).** We can wish to be treated in ways that
>   we recognize others are not duty-bound to treat us (or we them).²⁹
>   This is true even where one’s preferences are not defective. The
>   point is still more powerful when our preferences are uninformed
>   and mistaken.
>
> ²⁹  Boonin, David, ‘Against the Golden Rule Argument Against Abortion’, *Journal
>   of Applied Philosophy*, 14/2 (1997) 187–97.

Comment: Golden Rule against abortion... Well, if you don't exist, you can't retort.

Comment: In fact, your question is different. It is possible that we are wish someting to be done but think it's neither should be done nor shouldn't.